# Finding Terms and Scopenotes in DutchAAT dataset in Neo4j/Neosemantics

Tags: neo4j, neosemantics

I imported AAT-explicit **.nt files** into Neo4j with Neosemantics, and I'm trying to find mainly Dutch artforms that can have one or multiple definitions.

For instance the term *eludorisch schilderen*. I can find it with the cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:skosxl__Label) WHERE n.ns0__term = "eludorisch schilderen" RETURN n
```

And the corresponding definition with:

```
MATCH (n:ns0__ScopeNote) WHERE(n.ns1__identifier="101111") RETURN n
```

But the term and the scopenote should be linked, but I don't see the relations that connects them with eachother.
I'm aware of the property and value: uri = 'http://vocab.getty.edu/language/nl'

I understand that this is more a data question, but hope someone can help me explaining what is necessary.

Comment: Where can we find that AAT-explicit .nt files? What/where is the data model? Please help us to load the data so that we can take a look.

Comment: http://vocab.getty.edu/dataset/aat/explicit.zip http://vocab.getty.edu/